# Font-awesome CDN JS showing as render-blocking on Pagespeed Insights

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Instead of directly linking to the Font Awesome CSS, I am using the js from [Font Awesome CDN](https://cdn.fontawesome.com) to allow async loading of the icons on the homepage but Google's Pagespeed Insights still marks it as a render-blocking js.

I am using the custom js link provided by Font Awesome CDN and putting it in the `<head>` section (I could put it towards the end of the `<body>` also but thats where Font Awesome CDN asks me to put it).

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/mycustomcode.js"></script>
```

And yes, I have turned on Async loading by logging into my account on Font-Awesome-CDN.

Comment: Isn't everything inside the <head> "render-blocking"? The render will not start unless the js file has loaded. This does not means that the rest of the Font Awesome will block the render.

Comment: @GramThanos: your point makes sense. Font-awesome tries to get it's js to load the css asynchronously but the js itself is render-blocking. To take care of the warning on Google PageSpeed Insights, I have moved the script towards the end of the `<body>` now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in @GramThanos's comment, everything inside the `<head>` is render-blocking. Font-awesome CDN makes the CSS load asynchronously which does speed it up but Google would still see the JS as render-blocking.

Moving the JS near the end of the `<body>` helped it to not be render-blocking and also get rid of the PageSpeed Insights warning.

Answer (score 15):

As noted above, everything in the `<head>` is render-blocking.

Another approach is to include the async or defer attributes in the  tag:

```html
<script async src="https://use.fontawesome.com/mycustomcode.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/mycustomcode.js"></script>
```

@Anupam suggested (rightly) moving the  tag to the end of the body, but even [FontAwesome suggests including the defer attribute too](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-asynchronous-loading).

Flavio Copes has a [good explanation of script async vs. defer](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share how I reduced the loading page in over 50% with just one change in the way I was loading Font Awesome. Instead of including the script tag directly in the html file, I loaded the js file programmatically via javascript:

```
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/solid.js'
document.head.appendChild(script);

script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/brands.js'
document.head.appendChild(script);

script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/fontawesome.js'
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: The `defer` attribute postpones loading the script until the document is parsed. There's no need to execute JavaScript, browsers support it natively.

Comment: @ericek111 I understand your point but have you measured? I don't know why but this way is faster for me and also has better results with pagespeed. Don't downvote answers that may work for other people.

Comment: This simply injects the external JS whenever the parser stumbles upon your code. There are no `async` or `defer` attributes and it will block until your FontAwesome JS completely loads. I doubt this would be faster than `async`-ed and `defer`-red script tag. Also, I don't know where'd you get that I downvoted your post.